# Problemas com atualização da página em ajax

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde amigos!
Estou patinando e não saio do lugar, a estrutura do código é a seguinte:

inserir.php

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'action.anuncio.php',
   data: dados,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response) {
            location.reload();
      }
});
```

---

action.anuncio.php

```
include_once 'class.anuncio.php';
$anuncio = new Anuncio();
switch ($_POST[]) {
    case 1:
       $anuncio->inserir('informações');
       break;


}
```

---

class.anuncio.php

```
include_once 'conexao.php';
public Anuncio() {
    function listarAnuncios() {}
    function inserir(){
           /*instruçoes sql para gravação*/
           if($result) {
                $response = array('sucess'=>sucess);
                encode_json($response);
            }
      }


}
```

O código grava e exclui só que não atualiza a página, preciso apertar F5 para atualizar, parece que o gatilho do ajax não está recebendo a resposta correta para dar o reload.

Comment: Quando você especifica `dataType: 'json',`, a resposta do servidor deve ser uma resposta com um JSON valido no corpo e um cabeçalho `Content-type: application/json`. Como está o retorno do php? você setou o cabeçalho? uma sugestão: se você não quer nenhuma resposta de volta (você faz reload), não precisa esperar um JSON. Apenas envie um código 200 em caso de sucesso e um código 403 por exemplo, em caso de erro. Outra dica, se me permite: verifique a aba *Network* do *Developer Tool* (Ferramenta do desenvolvedor) e tente localizar esta requisição e o que ela está retornando, se é o esperado.

Answer (score 0):

A função *success* não está sendo chamada. A verdade é que muitos motivos podem causar isso, tens como, por exemplo, colocar um `console.log(dados)` para que possamos ver o que está sendo passado como JSON?

Outra dica é substituir o código em action.anuncio.php removendo o *SWITCH* da seguinte forma:

```
if(isset($_POST['chave'])) $anuncio->inserir('informações');
```

Assim impedindo erros de *undefined* no lado do PHP.